# Integer type not working as expected (Java)

Tags: java, generics, integer

I'm writing one of my first programs dealing with generics and standard OOP principles in Java, however I am running into a bit of a problem when dealing with the Integer type.

I noticed that Integers are expected to have a method named compareTo(Integer anotherInteger) in order to compare them as you would ints.

However, when I tried to implement this method in my program I ran into a problem.

error cannot find symbol
symbol: method compareTo(Integer)
location: variable x of type Integer
where Integer is a type-variable: Integer extends Object declared in BinarySearchTree

Essentially, I have x.comporeTo(y) where x & y are of type Integer, but the compareTo method is not found for variable of type Integer (x). Not sure how to solve this, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: I've provided a small example below to highlight my problem. I believe I am shadowing Integer, but I don't know how to get around doing such, or how to fix the problem,

```
    public class IntgS<Integer>
    {
            Intg<Integer> z = new Intg(3);
            Intg<Integer> y = new Intg(2);
            int w = (z.getX()).compareTo(y.getX());

            public class Intg<Integer>
            {
                    private Integer x;
                    public Intg(Integer x)
                    {
                            this.x = x;
                    }

                    public Integer getX()
                    {
                            return x;
                    }
            }
    }
```

This gives the same error expressing that Integer type-variable z.getX() does not have a method .compareTo(Integer).

Comment: Could you provide source code of treeBuilder.java please?

Comment: Post the relevant code

Comment: You can't expect us to help you with an error for which you have provided only an error message ... but no code.

Comment: And please add textual content as text, not as image. Google cannot index the text if it is in an image.

Comment: Sorry -- source code can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/byrnesj1/csc130/src/deb3731f8a1f3f5e4981210dd321970a9b784045/Proj2/simple/?at=master . Relevant files are BinarySearchTree.java and BinaryNode.java

Comment: Fixed it. Solution: declare the variable x as type int and the return type of method getX() as int. I suppose I didn't fully understand the generic type Integer.. time to read up

Answer (score 6):

According to the error message `BinarySearchTree` has a type parameter called `Integer` which shadows the standard type `java.lang.Integer`.

Just remove the type parameter in both classes, i.e.

```
class IntgS { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you Henry for the direction. Any way you can explain further on how shadowing relates to the code fragment I provided above?